# Find the maximum distance the ball will travel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

A ball is being thrown at initial speed of $v_0=7$ m/s with an angle $\theta$.

I am trying to find the maximum distance the ball will travel before hitting the ground.

At first i wanted to find the angle $\theta$ s.t. the ball will travel maximum distance but I'm not sure how to do it.

Is there any closed formula?

Thanks.

Comment: It is easy to answer, The formula of Range of projectile motion is $ R  = \frac{u^2\sin (2\theta)}{g}$  , differentiate w.r.t. $\theta$ as $f =\frac{\mathrm {d} R}{ \mathrm {d}\theta} = \frac{2u^2\cos (2\theta)}{g} $. The point where $f$ is zero in $ (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ is the angle of max range. And it is always $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the range of a projectile can be proven to be : $$R = \frac{v_i^2 \text{sin}(2\theta_i)}{g}$$

For constants $v_i$ and $g$, $R$ obtains it's maximum value when $\text{sin}(2\theta_i) = 1$. As $\theta_i ∈ [0, π/2]$ this corresponds to $\theta_i = π/4$.

You should be able to take it from here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the projectiles motion as a function of time. The conditions on which the projectile reaches its max distance, is that y=0. Solve for the time at which y=0, and then input that time into the equation for the projectiles x position